# firebase cloud functions return nested documents

Tags: javascript, java, json, firebase

I'm using firestore database and I am trying to retrieve data from a collection, but the data is related to another document in another collection.

What I'm trying to do is the following:

```
exports.acc = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  let docRef = admin.firestore().collection('LoggedIn').doc('CurrentLogin');
  snapshot = await docRef.get();
  doc = snapshot.data();
  usr = doc["Email"];  
  
// I want to get the Level from the Current Logged In user (the 'usr' below)
  let docRef1 = admin.firestore().collection('Accounts').doc(usr);
  snapshot1 = await docRef1.get();
  doc1 = snapshot1.data();
  usr1 = doc1["Level"];
  
  return res.send(usr1);
});
```

I've spent the last day just trying and trying with no luck, if I do one document it works, for example when I do this:

```
exports.acc = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  let docRef = admin.firestore().collection('LoggedIn').doc('CurrentLogin');
  snapshot = await docRef.get();
  doc = snapshot.data();
  usr = doc["Email"];  
  
  return res.send(usr);
});
```

It really returns the email address for the current logged in user.

why is the code above not working? what am I doing wrong ?

Any help is greatly appreciated

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem, turns out it was because the 'Level' is an integer value, so I had to add toString(), like that:

```
usr1 = doc1["Level"].toString();
```